Are questions on 3rd party software on-topic?
I'm considering this question in particular. This seems like the kind of question that belongs in the developers documentation or support forum.

Technically, all support for software belong in the associated forum/bug-tracker...yet we have a ton of them on SU/SF/SO.
If you want to allow software questions, you have a gray zone which overlaps with SU. The next problem is, if software is allowed, should games be allowed, too? That would overlap with Gaming.
Personally I'd limit the scope to exclude software/gaming questions which are not directly related with building stuff or blocks.
On-Topic:

How do I build structure x in software y.
What is this part in software y, and does it really exist?
Does this structure in game z really exist?

Off-Topic:

Software y crashes, why?
I'm stuck at level 42 in game z, what to do?
My harddisk crashed and all my blue Lego bricks have been eaten by a grue but I want to build a lake! HELP ME! 


But I've built a multi-colour Grue hunter with my Mindstroms that Might help with the blue brick problem ;)
